# How to make custom Template for Django Form Wizard properly display validation errors?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

This question is a follow-up to the question I posted and the answers it received here: [How to change the layout for templates in a Django Form-Wizard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670531/how-to-change-the-layout-for-templates-in-a-django-form-wizard)

I have made a 4-step form wizard. I have connected up 4 custom templates corresponding to each of the forms. Each such template extends a template named form_base.html.

I want to customize the layout on each of these forms. So I need to manipulate the form elements individually.  One of the elements on the first form is named "comment1". So in the template, I have:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th align="right">
            Comment #1
        </th>
        <td>
            {{ wizard.form.comment1 }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This partially works. It works fine if the user types a valid entry in that field. However if the user types invalid data, the error message does not appear. How can I fix this to show the error message properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs go over this thoroughly (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template). You can access and display the form errors and field errors by accessing them directly off the form and fields respectively. Here is an example.

```
{{ wizard.form.non_field_errors }}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th align="right">
            Comment #1
        </th>
        <td>
            {{ wizard.form.comment1 }}
        </td>
        {% if wizard.form.comment1.errors %}
        <td>{{ wizard.form.comment1.errors }}</td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
</table>
```